# In cypress how do I intercept the same url but with a different payload

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

My application is making it's calls to backend from the same url, but with different payloads. How can I test that those requests (that differ only in payload) are made with cypress when url is always the same? Here is what Ido

```
const requests = ProductList.initialRequestList;
const aliases = [];

requests.forEach((request, index) => {
  cy.intercept('POST', `${baseUrl}${request.endpoint}`, (req) => {
    if (req.body.query && req.body.query === request.payload.query) {
      aliases.push(`@${request.payload.query}`);
    }
  }).as(request.payload.query);
});

cy.visit('/someurl');

cy.wait(aliases)
  .then(() => {
    aliases.forEach((alias, index) => {
      // aliases ok/different here
      console.log(alias);

      cy.get(alias)
        .then((interception: cy.intercept.Interception) => {
          // here not ok all the same
          console.log(interception.response.body.message);
        });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initially I posted the Cypress docs on [dynamic alias](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Aliasing-individual-requests), but it turns out they are not very dynamic.

---

#### A reproducible test

Here's a Cypress test to replicate the problem, based on the code you added above.

- using a `fireFetches()` function to send the requests instead of `cy.visit()`
- stubbing the `cy.intercept()` response since I have no API endpoint to hit
- added `middleware: true` to allow all intercepts (a, b & c) to check the interception against the request data.
- only the request that matches `body.query === request.payload.query` will respond

```js
const baseUrl = 'domain/api/'     
const requests = [
  {endpoint: '1', payload: {query: 'a'}},
  {endpoint: '1', payload: {query: 'b'}},
  {endpoint: '1', payload: {query: 'c'}}
]

function  fireFetches() {      // for testing only, since I don't have app
  cy.window().then(win => {
    requests.forEach(request => {
      const url = `${baseUrl}${request.endpoint}`
      win.fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ query: request.payload.query })
      })
    })
  })
}

requests.forEach(request => {
  cy.intercept({
    method: 'POST', 
    url: `**/${baseUrl}${request.endpoint}`, 
    middleware: true
  }, (req) => {
    const body = JSON.parse(req.body)
    if (body.query === request.payload.query) {
      req.reply({message: `response for "${request.payload.query}"`})
    }
  })
  .as('endpoint')
})

fireFetches()

requests.forEach(() => {

  cy.wait('@endpoint').then(interception => {
    const body = JSON.parse(interception.request.body)

    if (body.query === 'a') {
      expect(interception.response.body.message).to.eq('response for "a"')
    }
    if (body.query === 'b') {
      expect(interception.response.body.message).to.eq('response for "b"')
    }
    if (body.query === 'c') {
      expect(interception.response.body.message).to.eq('response for "c"')
    }
  })
})
```

[image]

---

#### Your test - one intercept, checking at the cy.wait() end

For you the API server will provide the response, you don't need to mock the response and therefore you only need one `cy.intercept'

```js
const requests = ProductList.initialRequestList;

const url =  `**/${baseUrl}${requests[0].endpoint}` // endpoint is common
cy.intercept('POST', url).as('endpoint')

cy.visit('/someurl')

// differentiate requests at cy.wait()
requests.forEach(() => {
  cy.wait('@endpoint').then(interception => {
    const body = JSON.parse(interception.request.body)
    if (body.query === request.payload.query) {
      expect(...)
    }
  })
})
```

---

#### Waiting only once and expecting `cy.get(${request}.all)` to work

Summarizing the comments below, Artoo proposes to use

```js
cy.wait(${request}).then(() => cy.get(${request}.all)...
```

but the problem is `cy.get(${request}.all)` doesn't actually wait for ***all*** responses, it only gets whatever has responded ***so far*** in the test.

Since you are relying on actual responses from the API server (not mocking), the results will be asynchronous and not predicatble.

So, you ***must*** `cy.wait(${request})` n-times as shown by Filip Hiric in his video [Intercepting multiple requests](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cu5gdZtIq3w)

Comment: it has worked when I had one call in the same test but did not worked when I had many calls in the same test. I always get results from one call/intercept.

Comment: in cy.wait('@endpoint').then(interception => ... first interception  is undefined

Comment: and I need to get the response data to check what is coming. In this case I get what I send

Comment: I found a solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cu5gdZtIq3w. export const waitAllRequests = (request) => {
    cy.wait(`${request}`).then(() =>
        cy.get(`${request}.all`).then(($requests) => {
            $requests.forEach((element) => {
                if (element.responseWaited === false) {
                    cy.wait(request);
                }
            });
        })
    );
};

Comment: Sadly, that could be flaky if the `.then()` is processed before other requests have completed, since you are actually only waiting for one of the requests.

Comment: For your previous question, response data is available to check in the interception data after `cy.wait('@endpoint')` (see above).

Comment: BTW the video doesn't have the `cy.get(${request}.all)` idea you think is going to work. It shows a simpler version of the answer I gave you.

Comment: `cy.get(${request}.all)` is not actually waiting for ***all*** requests, it's just getting all that have happended ***so far***. Because requests are asynchronous, you ***must*** wait however many times the request occurs.

Comment: I have found other solution: instead of giving exact url in interception like: '${baseUrl}${request.endpoint}' I gave '\*\*${request.endpoint}*' and everything has worked. Special thanks go to user TesterDick!

Comment: I have tried the above both solutions but none works. Can you please help?

Comment: my requirements are to get the payload which react is sending to the app and compare it with the payload which backend(db/ecosystem ) has.

Comment: win.fetch is working fine but not getting how to get its response and check with the paylaod, also here we are sending payload  and not getting from our app.

Comment: win.fetch is only for simulation in the above example - you don't need it because React is firing the fetches.